# TypeError Reflect.defineMetadata is not a function, pure TS project

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflect-metadata

I've been trying to save some metadata about methods + classes using reflect-metadata, [similarly to this package.](https://github.com/seanpmaxwell/overnight/blob/master/src/core/lib/decorators.ts)

I'm using Typescript with both `experimentalDecorators` and `emitDecoratorMetadata` set to true. I have installed `reflect-metadata` via npm and am importing it at the top. I also have access to types and I can see details about the method `Reflect.defineMetadata()`.

`tsc` compiles fine without any errors but at runtime I'm always hitting:

```
TypeError at Object.defineMetadata (PATH\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:228:23)
```

Also, when importing `reflect-metadata` using: `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` .defineMetadata is truly not a function available under the typings, only defineProperty seems to be a thing.

[The full context of my code can be found here.](https://github.com/decorfn/firebase/tree/master/src)